# Get String from json with nested json object and nested json arrays with multiple json

Tags: json

I need to display json data in below format.how to get in proper format.Thanks

```
 {"IsValid":true,"Values":{"editions":[]},"error":null}
```

Comment: you will need to give a little more information. What language are you using, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ jq . <<< '{"IsValid":true,"Values":{"editions":[]},"error":null}'
{
  "error": null,
  "Values": {
    "editions": []
  },
  "IsValid": true
}
```

Comment: I need to use rest web service call using java ...Can you please let me know the code snippet for above format using Json & Json array in java